# Printing on Windows 8 64-Bit through Windows Server 2008 (32 Bit) RemoteApp

Tags: windows, printing, remoteapp

We have a network where our server is running on Windows Server 2008 (32 Bit) and a client computer is running on Windows 8.1 (64 bit) with a local printer attached to the client.  The printer is an HP P1006.

The remote app works well but when trying to print we get an odd "error 545".  We have tried both using the "connect client printer" function in remoteapp and also making the printer shared over the network and printing to it via the network from within the remoteapp.  Nothing works.  We can print a test page from the server to the client computer just fine, but it seems from remoteapp we cannot.

We have also tried installing the 32 bit drivers on the 64 bit machine as both the primary and secondary drivers but cannot get them to install.  Suggestions please?  We've been going crazy over this issue.